# Primeng 17 and Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, primeng

It is possible to use `primeng ^17.6.0` and `bootstrap ^5.3.2` in an Angular 17 project? I want to use bootstrap for the public part of my application, but there is an admin section where I would like to use primeng. According to the documentation: https://primeng.org/guides/csslayer#bootstrap I have to use layers and it mentions that I should use `bootstrap-reboot.css`. Can someone guide me on how I should use this?
He intentado lo siguiente:

angular.json

```
 "styles": [
   "src/styles.scss"
 ],
 "scripts": [
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"
 ],
```

package.json

```
"bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
"primeng": "^17.6.0",
```

component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Bootstrap</button>
<p-button label="Primeng"></p-button>
```

If I set my styles like this:

styles.scss

```
@layer bootstrap, primeng;
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss" layer(bootstrap);
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
```

I get the following result:

[image]

If I change the order to:

```
@layer bootstrap, primeng;
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss" layer(bootstrap);
```

I get:

[image]

If I change to:

```
@layer reboot, primeng;
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss" layer(reboot);
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
```

I get:

[image]

So is there any way the two can coexist?